# Using 3rd party PASCAL_VOC in arcgis.learn prepare_data() method

Tags: python, arcgis-python-api, machine-learning, deep-learning

Has anyone had luck using the prepare_data method with data not exported from the **Export Training Data** tool in ArcGIS Pro? The d[ocumentation suggests prepare_data](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.arcgis.com%2Fpython%2Fapi-reference%2Farcgis.learn.html%23prepare-data) will take PASCAL_VOC_rectangles from other sources.

I tried doing the following:

```
prep = prepare_data(path,dataset_type='PASCAL_VOC_rectangles')
```

but keep getting:

```
Please check your dataset. 26 images dont have the corresponding label files.
```

Per the [1.7 release of the Python API](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.arcgis.com%2Fpython%2Fguide%2Frelease-notes%2F), the **prepare_data** should be able to take XMLs produced from [LabelImg](https://community.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftzutalin%2FlabelImg). This has not been working for me.

The **path** variable is the path to my folder containing two subfolders, **labels** and **images**. **Labels** contains my XMLs and the **images** contains (you guessed it) my TIFs. I have tried to mimic how these folders are formatted like in the **Export Training Data** tool does, and I still cannot get it to work. Now I know the the **Export Training Data** tool creates some extra files beyond these folders, like **.emd**, **map.txt**, something else, but even when I delete these files, and run the **prepare_data** on the folder created from ArcGIS Pro, it works (but it doesn't work for my images and XMLs used through LabelImg).

Folder structure matches in mine and Esri's.
​[image: folder structure]

```
----------------------------- DOES NOT WORK -------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
    <filename>outtif_7500_2500.tif</filename>
    <source>
        <annotation>ArcGIS Pro 2.1</annotation>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>2500</width>
        <height>2500</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1798</xmin>
            <ymin>1724</ymin>
            <xmax>1818</xmax>
            <ymax>1779</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1305</xmin>
            <ymin>1502</ymin>
            <xmax>1361</xmax>
            <ymax>1525</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1720</xmin>
            <ymin>1418</ymin>
            <xmax>1746</xmax>
            <ymax>1477</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1084</xmin>
            <ymin>1092</ymin>
            <xmax>1145</xmax>
            <ymax>1115</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1670</xmin>
            <ymin>727</ymin>
            <xmax>1737</xmax>
            <ymax>743</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1902</xmin>
            <ymin>869</ymin>
            <xmax>1963</xmax>
            <ymax>884</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
-‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍--------------------------- WORKS ---------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<annotation>
    <filename>000000001.tif</filename>
    <source>
        <annotation>ArcGIS Pro 2.1</annotation>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>256</width>
        <height>256</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <object>
        <name>1</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>42.44</xmin>
            <ymin>128.19</ymin>
            <xmax>160.13</xmax>
            <ymax>226.85</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain what the exact problem was, but I changed the naming schema of my TIFs (it used to include two periods in the name, perhaps that was throwing things off) and set the save directory in LabelIMG before I started labeling objects.

Everything worked smoothly after that.
[image]