# Loading labelled dataset in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, xml

I have downloaded data set from USGS.  I have images in tiff files and their data in XML format I want to upload it on ArcGIS Pro so that tiff files become labelled from XML files so that I can export them in chips and use them for deep learning.

What format does the ArcGIS Pro use for loading labelling?

How to convert XML to that format?

How to upload tiff file along with that format on ArcGIS Pro so that I can visualize the bounding boxes?

Below is an image of collection of all my dataset:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to convert the bounding boxes to a feature class in order to visualize them. You might need to parse the XML and create a feature class out of it.

Also if this is a standard XML such as Pascal VOC or imagenet, you can try this https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.learn.toc.html#prepare-data

I was able to find a similar question [Using 3rd party PASCAL_VOC in arcgis.learn prepare_data() method](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360153/using-3rd-party-pascal-voc-in-arcgis-learn-prepare-data-method?rq=1)

Thanks,
Sandeep